# Jquery for loop sleep

Tags: jquery

How can I make this for loop sleep between the click functions on `.create_reservation`? Right now they are all clicking at the same time on `.create_reservation1` to `20`

```
$( "#button-1" ).click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
        var order_s = 20;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < order_s; i++) {
            $(".create_reservation" + i).click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For how long? Will it require user input to continue the loop? I am going to need a lot more information to be able to help you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there's a better way to do it than raising 20 click events.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe you are right. But i just needed the exact function that Rion Williams below gave me. Thank's anyway =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a function that accept a callback (i.e. what you want to do) and a delay that you want to apply between each item in your collection using the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function :

```
// callback is the function you want to execute and timeout is the
// delay in milliseconds between each
function clickTheButtons(callback, timeout) {
    // Store the buttons you need to click (every element that starts 
    // with .create_reservation)
    var buttons = $('[class^="create_reservation"]');
    // Store the current button you are on (so you know when to stop)
    var currentButton = 0;
    // Create a callback loop that will click each button
    // and wait until the next one
    (function processNextButton() {
        // Trigger your callback to process this current item
        callback.call(buttons[currentButton++]);
        // As long as there is one to process, do so
        if (currentButton < buttons.length) {
            // Indicate that you want to click the next button after the timeout
            // has elapsed
            setTimeout(processNextButton, timeout);
        }
    }());
}
```

And then simply call this via :

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?'){
     // Start clicking the buttons (1 second delay between each)
     clickTheButtons(function() { $(this).click();},1000);
}
```

You can [see an interactive example here](http://jsbin.com/teriyo/edit?html,output) and a demonstration below :

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Rion